# Define a topology on the set of integers

Tags: general-topology

Define a topology in the set of integers as follows: We declare that a set $U\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ is open if for every $a \in U$ there exists an integer m such that $a + m\mathbb{Z} \subseteq U$. Prove that
this notion of “open” indeed defines a topology on $\mathbb{Z}$.

I was able to show that the empty set, the set $\mathbb{Z}$, and the union of collection of sets in the topology are in the topology. I am having trouble proving the finite intersection part. I start with let U and V be in the topology and $a \in U \bigcap V$. Then for $a \in U$ there exists some m such that $a + m\mathbb{Z} \subseteq U$ and same for V with a different m. And this is where I get stuck. I know i need to define my m's for U and V differently but I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: If you have a finite collection of $U_i$ and associated $m_i$, take $m$ to be the least common multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the $m$ for $U$ and the $m'$ for $V$ and then take their product $mm'$. What do you know about $a+(mm')\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: So would it be sufficient to say:  Now let $U, V \in \tau$ and let $a \in U \cap V$. Then for $a \in U$, there exists an $m_1 \in Z$ such that $a + m_{1}Z \subseteq U$. And since $a \in V$, there exists an $m_{2} \in Z$ such that $a + m_{2}Z \subseteq V$. [Thus there exists an $m=m_{1}m_{2} \in Z$ such that $a + mZ \subseteq U \cap V$.].    Or

Comment: Or  [Then the product $m_{1}m_{2}=m \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$. So we have $m\mathbb{Z} \subseteq m_{1}\mathbb{Z} \bigcap m_2\mathbb{Z}$. Thus $a + m\mathbb{Z} \subseteq a + m_{1}\mathbb{Z} \subseteq U$ and $a + m\mathbb{Z} \subseteq a + m_{2}\mathbb{Z} \subseteq V$. Therefore $a + m\mathbb{Z} \subseteq U \bigcap V$. So $ U \bigcap V$ is in the topology. ]

Comment: Yes, that works. The important point is obviously to show that the $m$ you have chosen for $a$ satisfies $a+m\mathbb{Z}\subset U \cap V$.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!